# ¿Cómo puedo enviar solo el contenido de un archivo.txt al correo en Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Lo que quiero hacer es enviarme en texto(Mensaje) el contenido de un archivo.txt, no quiero enviarme el archivo al correo, solo quiero enviarme el contenido del archivo. Solo busco que me digan como puedo hacer eso o que me compartan un articulo sobre como hacer eso, no se como se le llama a eso, he investigado pero no he encontrado nada relacionado a lo que quiero hacer y hasta ahora solo he programado el envió del archivo.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import smtplib

def enviar(): 
   msg = MIMEMultipart("plain")
   msg["From"] = "mail_from"
   msg["To"] = "mail_to"
   msg["Subject"] = "Correo de Prueba"
   
   adjunto = MIMEBase("aplication", "octect-stream")
   adjunto.set_payload(open("send","r").read())
   adjunto.add_header("content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="mensaje.txt"')
   msg.attach(adjunto)
   
   smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com:587")
   smtp.starttls()
   smtp.login("mail_from","password")
   smtp.sendmail("mail_from","mail_to",msg.as_string())
   smtp.quit()
```

Comment: Utiliza el objeto `MIMEText(msg, 'plain')` donde `msg` representa al mensaje, que en tu caso sería `open("send", "r").read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar `MIMEText` para enviar un mensaje como texto plano.

```py
def enviar(): 
   msg = MIMEMultipart("plain")
   msg["From"] = "mail_from"
   msg["To"] = "mail_to"
   msg["Subject"] = "Correo de Prueba"
   
   mensaje= MIMEText(open("send","r").read(), "plain")
   msg.attach(mensaje)
   
   smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com:587")
   smtp.starttls()
   smtp.login("mail_from","password")

   smtp.sendmail("mail_from","mail_to",msg.as_string())
   smtp.quit()
```

Con esto ya sería todo. Si tienes alguna duda puedes hacérmela en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Muchas gracias, más tarde pruebo y te digo.

Comment: GRACIASS!!! si todo correcto ya me envié un correo y me mando el mensaje y no el archivo, mil gracias amigo, pensé que era mas complicado y no, ya se como es y se como funciona.

Comment: Amigo te di un voto, pero confírmame ¿si fue positivo? Porque veo que no lo puedo cambiar, quise darte un voto positivo pero, no sé si te di un voto positivo o negativo.

Comment: Lo que has hecho es aceptar la respuesta (lo cual es correcto). Para dar votos  positivos  das click en la flecha hacia arriba y para negativos la flecha hacia abajo. Para los votos negativos creo que debes de tener más de 125 de reputación ñ. Muchas gracias por aceptar la respuesta

Comment: Mmm vale y gracias!!! a ti porque puede hacer lo que quería.